# JavaScript action onbeforeunload executing before leaving page

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

Ive written some code Im trying to use to tack a visitors ip, and how long they are on site for.
Code:

```
<script>
var startTime = new Date();
window.onbeforeunload = $(function() {
    /* var ip = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer: document.location; */
    /* var ip = "192.168.1.1"; */
    var endTime = new Date();        //Get the current time.
    var timeSpent = (endTime - startTime);        //Find out how long it's been.
    var ip = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer: document.location; 
    $(window).load(function(event) {
         $.post('ajax.php', {ip: ip, timeSpent: timeSpent});
    });            
});
</script>
```

What I don't get, is why this does not wait till a user tries to leave the site before running this script.

Can anyone help me get this to wait until then to run?
Thank you!

Comment: You are setting `window.onbeforeunload` to a jQuery object, not a function.

Comment: Can this be modified to work?

Comment: Why are you using `$(window).load(` inside there?  I'd assume that when a user was leaving the page, the DOM would be ready.

Comment: This is one of those questions where it's like, man, you really don't know what this code is doing, do you?

Comment: Im trying to get the time on site. First by getting the start time, then, when a user leaves, grab the new time, the url of the parent window (this is iframed on 100+ sites), and use ajax to post to a php page and run more php with out a user prompt.

Comment: you only need to remove `$( ... )` around the function.

Answer (score 6):

There are a few issues with this code that I can see.

First off, `$(function(){})` is short-hand for `$(document).ready(function(){})`.  This means it will run the function when the DOM is ready, and then return you a jQuery object (`$(document)`).

Second, `$(window).load(function(){})` isn't needed.  I'd assume that when a user was leaving the page, the DOM would've already been loaded.

Third, `window.onbeforeunload` (and `window.onunload`) will *not* wait for your AJAX call to finish.  You can try to use `async:false` to make it wait (that may not work in all browsers).

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax.php',
    data: {ip: ip, timeSpent: timeSpent},
    async: false
});
```

(NOTE: `window.onbeforeunload` doesn't work in all browsers; I know Opera doesn't fire it.)

Also, `window.onbeforeunload` is used to ask the user if they want to leave the page or not.  If you return a string from the event that will be presented to the user (except in Firefox).

If you want to send an AJAX call when the user leaves the page, I suggest using `window.onunload` instead.

```
(function(){  // Anonymous function so startTime isn't global
    var startTime = new Date();
    window.onunload = function() { // set to a function
        var endTime = new Date();  //Get the current time.
        var timeSpent = (endTime - startTime);  //Find out how long it's been.
        var ip = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer: document.location; 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            data: {ip: ip, timeSpent: timeSpent},
            async: false
        });
    };
}());
```

Comment: Thanks for the `window.onunload` suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

You made a nice mess from this whole thing. All you need is:

```
var startTime = new Date();
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    var endTime = new Date();        //Get the current time.
    var timeSpent = (endTime - startTime);        //Find out how long it's been.
    var ip = (window.location != window.parent.location) ? document.referrer: document.location; 
    $.post('ajax.php', {ip: ip, timeSpent: timeSpent});
};
```

Comment: The browser won't wait for the AJAX call to finish, to this might not work.

Comment: @RocketHazmat no need to wait for it to finish, as far as I know firing the request is enough.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: But couldn't the page unload *before* the AJAX call was done?

Comment: @RocketHazmat can't be sure without testing... OP said it's working but guess we better test on several browsers. Will do that when having some time. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard: Maybe OP's server is so fast that the AJAX call finished in time! :)

Comment: I find that this works about 8/10 times when testing with friends all over the country. For some reason (above me) it does not work with out fail. I did ensure that everyone I tested this with had javsscript on and working.

Comment: @user1789437: It's like I said.  The page is unloading before the AJAX call finishes.  Try `$.ajax({url: 'ajax.php',data: {ip: ip, timeSpent: timeSpent},async: false});` instead.

Comment: I know this is a bit dated -- but what if you you set - async to false: but you close the session rather quickly, won't it still have a lifeline to the server. Or lets say the call timesout (you could put a timeout attribute) ? If you do this enough, won't it overload the server by having a bunch of open requests?

Comment: @jamesemanon I think Rocket had a point after all and if the document location was changed (or browser closed) before jQuery had a chance to send the actual request, the code will fail as no request will be sent.

Comment: @user1789437 just curious now, did you end up using `onunload` as Rocket suggested? Did it work 100% of the times?